# Finding Mutuals from a .txt file of numbers

Tags: python

I've got this code for school that's goal is to list all the mutuals (times two people have requested each other) from a list of values that represent people.

The list I'm using is:

```
1,9,11,15,20,3 
2,29,22,5,21,8  
3,2,30,16,27,2
4,21,17,25,6,4
5,15,2,18,6,24
6,1,18,19,29,4
7,30,17,30,18,15
8,10,2,6,26,12
9,21,30,12,29,14
```

The code I have to find mutuals is:

```
i=0
j=0
k=0
l=0
mutuals = []

for i in range(0,8):
    for j in range(i+1, 8):
        for k in range(1,5):
            if content2[j][k] == content2[i][0]:
                for l in range(1,5):
                    if content2[j][0] == content2[i][l]:
                       mutuals.append(content2[i][0])
                       mutuals.append(content2[j][0])
                       #print(mutuals)
                       print(i,j,k,l)
                       l=0
                    print(i,j,k,l)
            print(i,j,k,l)
     print(i,j,k,l)
print(i,j,k,l)
print(mutuals)
```

The reason I have listed 'print(i, j ,k ,l)' is so that I could try and see what was going wrong in the code.

The output is: `['2','5']`

Even though there should also be the mutuals ['2','8'] and ['4','6'] and I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong with the code.

How can I fix the code so that the other sets of mutuals are also printed as outputs?

Comment: What does your input list mean? What do the values represent?

Comment: From reading the code .. first number is the person's id followed by the list of people they requested.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The first person is their id and then the five people they requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than debug your code, here's an alternative solution which may give you some different ways to think about your problem

```
# Load the data as given
c2 = [[1,9,11,15,20,3],
     [2,29,22,5,21,8 ], 
     [3,2,30,16,27,2],
     [4,21,17,25,6,4],
     [5,15,2,18,6,24],
     [6,1,18,19,29,4],
     [7,30,17,30,18,15],
     [8,10,2,6,26,12],
     [9,21,30,12,29,14]]

# Convert it to a dictionary where the key is the person, and
# the value is a set of people they requested
c3 = { l[0]: set(l[1:]) for l in c2}

# Now crudely iterate through each person checking if
# they appear in the requests for each person they
# requested.
m = set()
for me,l in c3.items():
    for them in l:
        if me != them and me in c3.get(them,set()):
            # add the pair as a sorted tuple and let the set
            # deduplicate
            m.add(tuple(sorted([me,them])))
print(m)
```

This outputs

```
{(2, 5), (2, 8), (4, 6)}
```

It seems inefficient, but most of the searches are done using set access, which is constant time. The pairs are added as a tuple, not a list, as those are immutable and hence hashable (you can't put lists into a set).

This is just to get you thinking about using different data structures and  how they can dramatically change your algorithm choice.

Once you have your head around that, then the entire loop can be rewritten as a set comprehension

```
m = { tuple(sorted([me,them])) 
      for me in c3.keys() 
      for them in c3[me] 
      if me != them and me in c3.get(them,set())
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Your problem is your use of `range(start,stop)` - the 'stop' value is not inclusive, so if you want to test up to the `n`th value, you need to put `n+1` as the second argument.

i.e.

```
#...
for i in range(0,9):
    for j in range(i+1, 9):
        for k in range(1,6):
            if content2[j][k] == content2[i][0]:
                for l in range(1,6):
#...
```

As you can see, the 'mutual' of `2` is the final argument in its list `[2,29,22,5,21,8]`, likewise with the mutual of `6`: `[6,1,18,19,29,4]`.

Since your range loops for `l` and `k` only check `range(1,5)`, they stop just short of checking the final entry, and don't recognise them as mutuals.

---

### Code Review

**Note:** You do not need to initialise the values `i,j,k,l`, as they are reset in the first iteration of the `for` loop to the first value of the `range`.

You also do not need to reset `l` to `0`, as it is unused (except in your print statements) until it is reset in its `for` loop.

---

**Note:** a much simpler way of achieving this is thus:

```
for entry in nums:
    for test in nums[entry[0]:]:
        if entry[0] in test[1:] and test[0] in entry[1:]:
            print test[0], entry[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the massively nested loop approach and keeping track of a bunch of list indices, I'd build up a list of pairs so you can easily test if they've shown up before (unless you are going to run into memory issues there's no harm in copying / modifying your data).

```
requests = [
[1,9,11,15,20,3],
[2,29,22,5,21,8], 
[3,2,30,16,27,2],
[4,21,17,25,6,4],
[5,15,2,18,6,24],
[6,1,18,19,29,4],
[7,30,17,30,18,15],
[8,10,2,6,26,12],
[9,21,30,12,29,14]
]
all_pairs = []

#create one big list of pairs
for person in requests:
    pairs = []
    user_id = person[0]

    for other_person in person[1:]:
        pairs.append({user_id, other_person}) # add to the list of pairs (we use set so the order of the pair doesn't matter)
    all_pairs += pairs #add the pairs from one person to the global list

matches = []

#iterate over that list and check if we've seen that pair before
for index, pair in enumerate(all_pairs):
    if pair in pairs[:index]: #if we've seen it before
        matches.append(pair) #add it to our matches (if a pair is encountered a third time, it'll be added to matches twice)
```

This could be written a bit more compactly and efficiently, but my goal was rather to make it easy to understand the flow.